# Postman-Tests Runner - not all tests are ran/executed

Tags: postman

I am relatively new to Postman, so I created test cases for 6 APIs:

[image]

[image]

I click on Run, and I would expect that all APIs tests are executed, but it is only test cases for 2 API are executed:

[image]

What would be the reason that the tests for the rest 4 API are not executed?

I also noticed that if I do not execute the second POST, so the rest of the API test would run.

[image]

My second API (POST Creates the user group type.) contains postman.setNextRequest() method in the Tests.

[image]

Could it be that postman.setNextRequest interferes with the Runner ?

Comment: `postman.setNextRequest(request_name)` not `postman.setNextRequest(URL)`. And if you want to stop, `postman.setNextRequest(null)`, not `postman.setNextRequest("")`

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 , Thank you. I have done it as per your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used postman.setNextRequest() to run multiple requests in one API.
I found out that if I take away postman.setNextRequest(), and split one API on two APIs, so the API would be executed on Runner.  This is the one solution which I found so far